# Regex: match word that ends with “AM” (with case insensitive comparison)

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to compare text ends with "AM" using regex. With case insensitive input i.e.

- AM
- am
- Am
- aM

All should be valid scenario. I am trying below

```
myinput.match(/^\w*am\b$/)
```

But it is doing case sensitive comparison (i.e. for 'am' but not working for AM, Am, aM).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LZf7H/3585/)

Comment: `myinput.match(/^\w*am$/i)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add case intensive flag at the end:

```
myinput.match(/^\w*am\b$/i)
```

**Edit: as per your comment**

The issue with `07.15am` is the first part of your regex. If you want to be strict then you could try:

```
/^(\w+)(\.\w+)\s?(am)$/i
```

This will match `07.15am`, `07.15Am` or `07.15 AM`.

If you want to be a little looser you can make the second group optional.

```
/^(\w+)(\.\w+)?\s?(am)$/i
```

Also this wont work if you have anything before or after the string. I would suggest removing the ^$ boundaries.

```
/(\w+)(\.\w+)?\s?(am)/i
```

That should cover most cases.

Comment: `\b$` here is the same as `$`.

Comment: It is not working if input is: 07.15am